# How to structure Haskell applications?

Tags: haskell

I have some experience with simple (single-focus) Haskell programs but now I am trying to write bigger applications in Haskell. I am having trouble structuring the application.

Say, we have an application with three modules (conceptually) - `Main`, `Logic`, and `AppIO`. `Main` starts the program and uses functions in `Logic` and `AppIO` to do the work. `Logic` abstracts the app logic and we need multiple implementations of it. Which `Logic` implementation is used by `Main` is decided by user configuration. `AppIO` is for functions that talk to the outside world.

My `Main` module has a `newtype App = App { unapp :: ReaderT r (ExceptT e m) a }` monad transformer. Similarly, `Logic` and `AppIO` have their own monad transformer stacks. I am thinking of creating an `App` monad transformer with `Logic` and `AppIO` transformers at the base.

At this point I have some questions.

1. Is this a correct way to structure Haskell applications that have multiple monadic modules?
2. Should `Logic` and `AppIO` have their own monad transformer stacks or should they have `App` in their type signatures? I don't like `App` to be in module types as I think modules should be agnostic to each other. How will I give `Logic` its own state if I don't make it a transformer in itself?
3. If `Logic` and `AppIO` have their own `ExceptT` monads in their transformer stacks for error handling with their own error types i.e. `MonadError LogicError` and `MonadError IOError`, how would they work with `App` level `ExceptT`? Do I need to write `lift` functions? If I write `lift` functions then how do I have internal state (for example `RandomGen`) in `Logic` that is updated on function calls? From what I understand `lift` will run the monad and so its state is lost?
4. How do I write `Logic` so that it has multiple implementations that may be swapped with each other without having to change anything else? Should I define a `class Logic`? Or should it be a `data Logic` with its interface functions as members?

Comment: It's a stylistic matter, but I tend to find monads are best used over small scopes (like mutable variables). Instead of trying to make a big mother monad for your whole app, think about what data structures you need to keep as much of your logic pure as possible

Comment: Related: https://haskell-explained.gitlab.io/blog/posts/2019/07/28/polysemy-is-cool-part-1/index.html

Comment: @arrowd I'd like to avoid external libraries for now. What's the right way with core Haskell only?